# How to redirect multiple bash commands to a variable AND screen?

Tags: macos, bash, shell, redirection, pipe

I would like to capture a subshell's output in a variable and print it in the terminal screen simultaneously. Is it possible to do this by assigning the subshell to a variable and piping stdout and stderr to tee? The following script is not working.

```
$ cat test
#!/bin/bash

echo "Command before the redirected subshell"
OP=$(
    echo "Command in the redirected subshell 1"
    echo "Command in the redirected subshell 2"
    echo "Error in the redirected subshell" > /dev/stderr
    ) 2>&1 | tee /dev/tty
echo "Command after the redirected subshell"
echo "OP=$OP"
```

There is no output for the commands (except the one redirected to stderr) in the subshell and $OP seems to be a zero-length string.

Thanks for any idea!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
op=$( (cmd1; cmd2; ... ; cmdN) | tee /dev/tty )
```

Comment: Thanks! It is working now. So I need to create to nested shells then.